# Title not Emptying in a Widget

Tags: widgets, widget-text

```
<?php echo $args['before_title'].$title.$args['after_title'];   ?>
```

The above code generates the widget title. Here is it's admin image →[image]

Here is additional code:

```
<p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">
                    <?php echo __('Main Title:', 'charito');?>
                    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" />
                </label>
            </p>
```

Issue: when I empty the title in the backend and press save than by default its take the title 'SUBSCRIBE' Ideally it should be blank. what is causing this issue?

Comment: In both cases, where is `$title` being set, and what’s the code for saving the widget?

Comment: You mean this → ` $title = empty($instance['title']) ? __("Subscribe",'charito') : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);`

Comment: or This → `   $title               = strip_tags($instance['title']);
`

Comment: `$title = empty($instance['title']) ? __("Subscribe",'charito') : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);` 
This line specifically sets the title to Subscribe if no title is set. It's doing exactly what you've told it to do. Why is this line there if you don't want this behaviour?